# C# I want to bind Ingredients into recipe in listbox with a database

Tags: c#, sql, database, listbox

I want to add ingredient into recipe. I have tried many things in order to do that but it didn't work sadly.
Idea: http://prntscr.com/dw8lom
My database tables: http://prntscr.com/dw8ms7

My code I've used to add recipe:

```
   private void VoegReceptenToe()
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO Recipe VALUES (@RecipeName, 30, 'goed mixen')";

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))

        {
            connection.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeName", txtRecipeName.Text);
            command.ExecuteScalar();
            PopulateRecipes();

        }

    }
```

Populate recipe:

```
{
        string query = "SELECT a.Name FROM Ingredient a " + 
            "INNER JOIN Recipe_Ingredient b ON a.Id = b.IngredientId " +
            "WHERE b.RecipeId = @RecipeId";
        // de connectionstring hoef je niet te openen en te sluiten als,
        // je een using statement gebruikt, dat doet hij vanzelf.
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query,connection))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeId", lstRecipe.SelectedValue);

            DataTable ingredientTable = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(ingredientTable);
            //Dit displayt de listbox.
            lstIngredient.DisplayMember = "Name";
            lstIngredient.ValueMember = "id";
            lstIngredient.DataSource = ingredientTable;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "didn't work" means? What's the problem with your code? Does not insert the recipe in the database? Throws any exception?...

Comment: Thanks for the replys,
With it didn't work I mean; I have tried the following code:
 private void VoegIngredientenToe()
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO Ingredient VALUES (@IngredientName)";
            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IngredientName", textBox1.Text);
                command.ExecuteScalar();
                PopulateRecipes();

            }

        }

Comment: @PaulF I can't add a ingredient to a new recipe. For example Recipe: "nieuwtest"i've created by using the textbox value and insert that value to the listbox1. But I can't manage to do that for ingredients, and add it to the new "Recipe".

Comment: To add ingredients to a recipe then you need to be updating the Recipe_Ingredient table.

Comment: @PaulF, I've tried this code, but it doesn't work:  private void VoegIngredientenToe()
        {

            string query = "INSERT INTO Ingredient VALUES (@IngredientName)";

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))

            {
                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IngredientName", textBox1.Text);
                command.ExecuteScalar();
                

            }
            UpdateRecipe_Ingredients();

        }

Comment: private void UpdateRecipe_Ingredients()
        {
            string query = "UPDATE Recipe_Ingredient SET RecipeId = @IngredientId WHERE Id = @IngredientId";

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))

            {
                connection.Open();

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IngredientName", textBox1.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IngredientId", lstIngredient.SelectedValue);
                command.ExecuteScalar();
            }

Comment: The two sets of code you have shown are for adding new Recipes and new Ingredients. To add an Ingredient to a Recipe you need to be inserting entries to the Recipe_Ingredient table.

Comment: @overflowit: Your query would result in the RecipeId (which is a foreign key into the Recipe table) being set to the IngredientId (which is a foreign key into the Ingredient table) for the Recipe_Ingredient row that has a matching Id to the IngredientId.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a new connection to the database before closing the existing one.

What happens in your code is that when execution enters method `VoegReceptenToe` it opens a new connection to the database to insert some data. However, before closing that connection you're calling `PopulateRecipes` method which opens a new connection to the database.

What you have to do is to split insert and query operations and you can do this by moving the method `VoegReceptenToe` **after** the `using` statement:

```
private void VoegReceptenToe()
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO Recipe VALUES (@RecipeName, 30, 'goed mixen')";

    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecipeName", txtRecipeName.Text);
        command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    PopulateRecipes();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, changed it. But I'm still stuck on the ingredient part. :-(

Answer (score 0):

As long as you ensure that Recipe & Ingredient names are unique in their tables (maybe using a unique index) & you have made sure the RecipeName & IngredientName exist in the tables (e.g. by only selecting from your listboxes) then the following query may do what you want :

```
INSERT INTO Recipe_Ingredient (RecipeID, IngredientID)
VALUES (
SELECT ID FROM Recipe Where Name = @RecipeName,
SELECT ID FROM Ingredient Where Name = @IngredientName)
```

This inserts an entry into the Recipe_Ingredient table, consisting of the ID of the RecipeName & the IngredientName as long as there exists a single entry for each.

You will need to add parameters for both the RecipeName & IngredientName to your command and run the ExecuteNonQuery method as the INSERT does not return a value.

Similarly to add a new RecipeName the ExecuteNonQuery method should be used to run this query :

```
INSERT INTO Recipe (Name, PrepTime, Instructions) VALUES (@RecipeName, 30, 'goed mixen')
```

and for a new Ingredient

```
INSERT INTO Ingredient (Name) VALUES (@Ingredient)
```

Also take note of RePierre's reordering of your code to ensure connections are not prematurely closed.

Comment: I have tried to apply the query to my application, and I still didn't manage to do it :-(. Didn't reply quick because I thought I could figure it out (not)..

Comment: Can you show your modified code - also do you check for errors, if so are any reported.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! Sorry for my late reaction :D! I was so stubborn that I had to fix this asap that I didn't react :D. What I did was, make another listbox so in this case listbox 3, bind this with the table ingredients and add a multiclickevent! The only thing i'm figuring out now is how I use my delete button for an inner join xD.